# Bootstrap Popover fill input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap popover with default class .popover and an input with id #tags. Inside the popover I have a list with some links. I want to click a link and fill the input with content from

This is my code and what I've tried:

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover551732" style="top: 34px; left: 2px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">5 most recent</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <ul class="popover-content">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="first">First matter</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second matter</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Third matter</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth matter</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Fifth matter</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<input type="text" id="tags" ....
```

What I tried:

```
$(function(){
    $('.first').live('click', function() {
        $("#tags").val($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".popover-content a").click(function(){
       var value = $(this).html();
       var input = $('#tags');
       input.val(value);
    });
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8edt9hn/)

Comment: Your solution works on demo but an my script doesn't ... hmmm is there a problem if I have multiple popovers ... or an autocomplete to the same input?

Comment: give it a unique class name e.g. `<div class="popover-content newClassNm">`and replace `$(".popover-content a").click(function(){` using your new class name e.g. `$(".newClassNm a").click(function(){`

Comment: have you included the [jquery library](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js) successfully?

Comment: Yes ... of course . The other autocomplete works, the other popover work too, tooltips ,etc ...

Comment: The best thing would be to create a fiddle or provide more code to be able to find the issue.